# Jquery progressbar random image width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I really don't know what im doing wrong. I want to change the width of the image to a random number from 0 - 100%. Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

```
function progress(){


    $("body").append("<div class='main_div'></div>");

    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var x = 5;

    for(var i = 0; i < x; i++){


        $(".main_div").append("<div class='statusbar'></div>");
        $(".statusbar:nth-child(" + x + ")").append("<img src='project_status.gif'>");

        var c = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
        $(".statusbar:nth-child(" + x + ") img").css({ "width", "(" + c +")%" });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your `Math.floor()` function: Instead of

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
```

It should be

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
```

with the +1 within the `Math.floor` brackets.

I don't know if it would be helpful or not, but I have previously produced a random-size progress bar here: http://jsfiddle.net/cu22W/10/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I fix this problem. But the problem here

$(".statusbar:nth-child(" + x + ") img").css({ "width", "(" + c +")%" });

is still open

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this statement:

```
$(".statusbar:nth-child(" + x + ") img").css({ "width", "(" + c +")%" });
```

You should read up on JQuery `.css()` function : http://api.jquery.com/css/

But when you use the `.css()` function with `{ }` brackets the syntax is the same as CSS itself.

So for your statement the proper way would be :

```
.css({ width : c +"%" })
```

or, if you wanted to keep it the way you have it just remove the `{ }` brackets :

```
.css( "width", c +"%")
```

I am also pretty sure you don't need to wrap `c` in `()`